# I'm prompted on every reboot for a password for a stale iCloud account

Tags: icloud

I have had an iCloud account associated with a Gmail ID old@gmail.com. I then switched to another ID new@gmail.com, so I removed old@gmail.com from my iCloud account and entered new@gmail.com. This was an year or so back.

A few days back, I found an entry in the Keychain for old@gmail.com, so I deleted it. After that, I'm prompted one every reboot to enter the password for old@gmail.com:

[image]

I cancel it, but it comes up after every reboot. I tried entering my iCloud password, but it doesn't work.

How do I get this prompt to go away and never come back?

Comment: Have you confirmed that everything is setup correctly at the Apple ID website: https://appleid.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MyAppleId.woa/?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply (I think I missed your comment earlier). Yes, everything is set up correctly there. old@gmail.com is not listed.

Comment: ... And the problem seems to have disappeared, maybe with the 10.9.1 or .2 updates. Thanks for your help, bassplayer7.

Comment: Great to hear that everything is working correctly now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application icon suggests the password is being requested by Messages.app.

### Messages.app

Launch Messages.app and check the accounts listed in the preferences do not include or mention your stale `@gmail.com` account.

[image: Messages preferences toolbar]

### Internet Accounts

Look for legacy accounts in your Internet Accounts within System Preferences.app:

[image: System Preferences > Internet Accounts]

### Preferences

Check your preferences for mentions of the old address using the Terminal.app command:

```
grep -r old@gmail\.com ~/Library/Preferences/*
```

If this matches a file, modify the following command to examine the file's contents:

```
defaults read ~/Library/Preferences/MobileMeAccounts.plist > ~/Desktop/output.txt
```

In the example above, a new file called **output.txt** will appear on your desktop. This file can be opened with TextEdit.app.

This file may hint as to which application or tool has your old account listed.

If you find a matching preference, consider deleting or renaming it. The preferences will be lost but they should never contain critical information.

Remember to log out or restart after altering the preferences file.

Comment: That didn't help -- it lists new@gmail.com, and not old@gmail.com, but Apple confuses new@ for old@gmail.com. Turning my account off and on in Messages produces that prompt again asking me to type the password for old@

Comment: What do you see if you run the following Terminal.app command: `grep old@gmail\.com  ~/Library/com.apple.imservice.iMessage.plist`?

Comment: grep: /Users/kart/Library/com.apple.imservice.iMessage.plist: No such file or directory

Comment: Sorry, my last command missed a folder. How about if we widen the search: `grep old@gmail\.com ~/Library/Preferences/*` ?

Comment: Assuming you wanted to include subfolders, I did: grep -nr old@gmail\.com ~/Library/Preferences. The result was: Binary file /Users/kart/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.coreservices.appleidauthenticationinfo.<elided>.plist matches
Binary file /Users/kart/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.google.GoogleContactSync.<elided>.plist matches
Binary file /Users/kart/Library/Preferences/com.apple.ids.service.com.apple.private.alloy.maps.plist matches
Binary file /Users/kart/Library/Preferences/com.apple.spotlight.plist matches

Comment: Binary file /Users/kart/Library/Preferences/MobileMeAccounts.plist matches

Comment: Good to have found a reference to your old account. You can make a readable copy of the matching binary plist file using: `defaults read ~/Library/Preferences/MobileMeAccounts.plist > ~/Desktop/output.txt`. A file called **output.txt** will appear on your desktop; open it with TextEdit.app or another text editor.

Comment: Indeed -- that says: {
    Accounts =     (
                {
            AccountDSID = <elided>;
            AccountDescription = iCloud;
            AccountID = “old@gmail.com";

Comment: I have updated the answer based on your findings.

Comment: First, thanks so much Graham, for helping me with this. There's no legacy account in Internet Accounts in System Preferences. It's just the iCloud account new@gmail.com, which Apple still confuses for old@gmail.com, which it was. Should I just open that plist in the plist editor and change the email ID forcefully?

Comment: Better to delete the file and then re-enter your accounts. Under OS X 10.9, editing preferences directly is unlikely to be picked up by OS X or applications.

Comment: Sorry, I seemed to have dropped the ball on this. The problem seems to have disappeared, maybe with the 10.9.1 or .2 updates. I no longer get the prompts, and old@gmail.com is no longer in the plist file. Thanks for your help, Graham.